# In a Dataset with many categorical columns what should be preferred -One Hot encoding or Label encoding when doing regression?

Tags: regression, python, categorical-encoding

Suppose my Dataset for automobiles has a feature 'Number of cylinders' with labels 'One','Two'..(Strings) as categories,what should be preferred label encoding or One hot encoder?

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case 'Number of cylinders' is a discrete numerical variable not a categorical variable.

In general for categorical variable you can use label encoding if the levels of your categorical variable are somehow ordered (e.g. volume: small, medium, big) otherwise it is better to use one hot encoding.

Comment: In my case 'One','Two,,etc are string variables and not numerical,But I can see the confusion in question.Thats why i mentioned in quotes.Let me edit the question.

Comment: Generally One Hot Encoder is preferred to Labels as One Hot Encoder gives new columns with binary values which is easily understood by most algorithms.But I am asking in case of regression explicitly

Comment: That you elect to record actual numbers 1, 2, 3, etc. as strings does not change their meaning--it only makes it more difficult for you to analyze them appropriately.  One might still treat them as categorical or nominal variables in a model--but that's a modeling decision and it should not be determined solely by the physical data type or the conceptual data type.

Comment: The downside of one hot encoding in your case is that you lose information ( 3 cylinders > 2 cylinders > 1 cylinder). If this info is useful I would go for label encoding.